# Intersection of two cyclic groups in $D_{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, dihedral-groups

For the dihedral group $D_{n}=<\rho,\tau | \rho^{n}=\tau^{2}=id, \rho\tau=\tau\rho^{-1}>$

How can we prove that the intersection of $<\rho>$ and $<\tau>$ is the trivial group $\{e\}$, for all $n$? I know it is very obvious but I want to prove it formally.

Comment: It is not that difficult. What did you begin to write? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @AnneBauval I assumed that there exists an integer $m$ such that $\rho^{m}=\tau$. I don't know how should I proceed.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to realize $D_n$ as the isometry group of a regular $n$-gone ($\tau$ will be a reflexion, $\ne\rho^m$ a rotation). Even without knowing that this group $G$ "is" (isomorphic to) $D_n$, the existence of that $G$ and $r,t\in G$, for which the defining relations of $D_n$ are realized but not the relation $r^m=t$, proves what you want.

Comment: @AnneBauval I see what you are saying. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple argument.

If $\tau\in\langle \rho\rangle$, then $\tau$ commutes with $\rho$.

So $\tau\rho=\rho\tau=\tau\rho^{-1}$, hence $\rho=\rho^{-1}$, so $\rho^2=Id$ and $\rho$ has order $1$ or $2$. Hence $n=1,2$. If you assume $n\geq 3$ in your definition of $D_n$, we are done. If you allow $n=2$, then $D_n$ is the Klein group, and you can check your claim by hand.